# java parse JSON tree recursively get parentID and level

Tags: java, json

I have issue to find parentID and level values when parsing the JSON file recursively. Here is the JSON file and Java code:

```
{
  "user_quiz": [
    {
      "user_id": "55ce697e08b54122a0000214",
      "user_score": "26"
    },
    {
      "created": 1443115892,
      "answers": [
        {
          "answer": "3",
          "points": "4",
          "complete": "true"
        },        
        {
          "answer": "30",
          "points": "40",
          "complete": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_id": "55ce697e08b54122a0000214",
      "quiz_id": "30061"
    }
  ]
}
```

Java code:

```
...

int id = 0, parentID = 0, level = 0;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       
JsonParser parser = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(new File("/Downloads/nnn.json"));

while (!parser.isClosed()) {
        JsonToken token = parser.nextToken();

        if (token == null) {
            break;
        }

        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(parser);

            if (node.isArray()) {
                parseArray(node);
            }
            else if (node.isObject()) {
                parseObject(node);
            }
        }
}

...

public static void parseArray(JsonNode node) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {  
    if (node.isArray()) {
        for (int i=0; i<node.size(); i++) {

            JsonNode temp = node.get(i);

            if (temp.isArray()) {
                parseArray(temp);
            }
            else if (temp.isObject()) {
                parseObject(temp);
            }
        }   
    }
}

...

public static void parseObject(JsonNode node) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException { 
    if (node.isObject()) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode iterator=node.getFields();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String,JsonNode jsonNode=iterator.next();             

            String key = jsonNode.getKey();             
            JsonNode temp = jsonNode.getValue();            

            System.out.println("level="+level);
            System.out.println(tabs+"(id="+(++id)+",parentID="+parentID+")=="+key+"="+temp.toString());

            if (temp.isArray()) {
                parseArray(dtemp);
            }
            else if (temp.isObject()) {
                parseObject(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me change the code in order to get parentID and level values ?

**EDIT**

So I would want to have the following result:

```
    1. 
    key=user_quiz 
    val=user_quiz=[{"user_id":"55ce697e08b54122a0000214","user_score":"26"},{"created":1443115892,"answers":[{"answer":"3","points":"4","complete":"true"},{"answer":"30","points":"40","complete":"false"}]},{"user_id":"55ce697e08b54122a0000214","quiz_id":"30061"}]
    id=1 
    parent_id=0 
    level=0

    2.  
    key=user_id 
    val="55ce697e08b54122a0000214" 
    id=2 
    parent_id=1
    level=1

    3.  
    key=user_score
    val="26" 
    id=3 
    parent_id=1 
    level=1

    4. 
    key=created 
    val=1443115892 
    id=4 
    parent_id=1 
    level=1

    5.  
    key=answers 
    val=[{"answer":"3","points":"4","complete":"true"},{"answer":"30","points":"40","complete":"false"}]
    id=5 
    parent_id=1 
    level=1

    6.  
    key=answer 
    val="3" 
    id=6 
    parent_id=5 
    level=2

    7.  
    key=points 
    val="4" 
    id=7 
    parent_id=5 
    level=2

    8.  
    key=complete 
    val="true" 
    id=8 
    parent_id=5 
    level=2

    9.  
    key=answer 
    val="30" 
    id=9 
    parent_id=5 
    level=2

    10.  
    key=points 
    val="40" 
    id=10 
    parent_id=5 
    level=2

    11.  
    key=complete 
    val="false" 
    id=11 
    parent_id=5 
    level=2

    12. 
    key=user_id 
    val="55ce697e08b54122a0000214" 
    id=12 
    parent_id=1 
    level=1

    13. 
    key=quiz_id 
    val="30061" 
    id=13 
    parent_id=1 
    level=1
```

So:

```
  id = should increment on each new key
  parent_id = is ID of parent key on which child belong
  level = is level of depth, see on answers it's increased
```

Comment: what's your parent id ??

Comment: Pls explain question in detail

Comment: There is no "level" in the JSON either

Comment: id = should increment on each new key
  parent_id = is ID of parent key on which child belong
  level = is level of depth, see on answers it's increased